# How can I solve error of ": Incompatible shapes" in tensorflow CNN?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am beginner in Tensorflow and I try to create a CNN to classify images,this is my code for training model:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


X=pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb"))
Y=pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb"))

print(X.shape[1:])
X=X/255.0
print("_____________________________________")
print(X.shape[1:])
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=64,validation_split=0.1)
```

and this is fo image preprocessing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os 
import random

DATADIR="C:/myDirectory/PetImages"
CATEGORIES=["Dog","cat"]

IMG_SIZE=50

training_data=[]

def create_training_data():
    for categorie in CATEGORIES:
        path=os.path.join(DATADIR,categorie)

        class_num=CATEGORIES.index(categorie)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)   
                new_array=cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

 create_training_data()
 print(len(training_data))

 random.shuffle(training_data)

X=[]
Y=[]

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)

X=np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)

print(X.shape[1:])
import pickle

pickle_out=open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()


pickle_out=open("Y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(Y,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

And i got this error :
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [64,1] vs. [64,11,11,1]
     [[{{node metrics/acc/Equal}}]]

If someone know another way to classifying images in tensorflow using its own dataset images ,help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that, you have not used the Flatten() between the Conv and the Dense layers. Dense layers cannot handle the direct output of the Conv layers, so they need to be flattened.

Example:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When adding Flatten() I get this error: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
  [[{{node loss/activation_3_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]

Comment: You are trying to use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, so the output layer should be: model.add(Dense(2)) model.add(Activation("softmax"))

Comment: You can use the sigmoid activation, but you should use binary crossentropy for that

Comment: The output layer nodes should equal the number of classes that you have, for sparse crossentropy and softmax activation for what you are trying to achieve